# Poor results on image classification with CNN and VGG16 transfer learning

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I trained a 7-class image classifier to predict the brand of handbags using Keras and VGG16 transfer learning. I have 1000 sample images per class and used image augmentation on the fly to enhance the dataset. Surprisingly it returned poor training and validation accuracy. Also, I set early-stopping and reduce LR on plateau callbacks which kicked in at epoch 40 out of 50 left me with 14% training and 10% validation accuracy. This is weird as a dumb-classifier would get a bit more than 14% accuracy.
I tried the same set with ResNet50 this time and 17% and 19% for training and validation accuracy respectively at epoch 6 out of 50 ( early-stopping callback kicked in)

I am putting my code here for you folks to see if there is anything I might have missed here.

```
image_shape = (224, 224)
batch_size = 128

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   brightness_range = (0.5,1.5),
                                   rotation_range=10, 
                                   width_shift_range=0.1,
                                   height_shift_range=0.1,
                                   shear_range=0.15, 
                                   zoom_range=0.1,
                                   channel_shift_range = 10, 
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   validation_split= 0.2
                                   )
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                  validation_split= 0.2)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(dst_dir,
                                                    target_size=image_shape,
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    seed = 835,
                                                    subset= "training",
                                                    class_mode = "sparse"
                                                    )
val_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(dst_dir,
                                                 target_size=image_shape,
                                                 batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 seed = 835,
                                                 subset="validation",
                                                 class_mode = "sparse"
                                                 )

# Define some callbacks
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping( monitor="val_loss", 
                                                   min_delta=0,
                                                   patience=5,
                                                   verbose=0,
                                                   mode="auto",
                                                   baseline=None,
                                                   restore_best_weights=False,
                                                   )
reduceLR = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss",
                                                factor=0.1,
                                                patience=5,
                                                verbose=0,
                                                mode="auto",
                                                min_delta=0.0001,
                                                cooldown=0,
                                                min_lr=0,
                                                )

#Transfer learning with VGG16
vgg16_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(pooling='avg', 
                                          weights='imagenet', 
                                          include_top=False, 
                                          input_shape=image_shape +(3,)
                                          )
for layers in vgg16_model.layers:
            layers.trainable=False
last_output = vgg16_model.layers[-1].output
vgg_x = Flatten()(last_output)
vgg_x = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(vgg_x)
vgg_x = Dense(7, activation = 'softmax')(vgg_x)
vgg16_final_model = tf.keras.Model(vgg16_model.input, vgg_x)
vgg16_final_model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
                          optimizer= 'adam', 
                          metrics=['acc'])
vgg16_final_model.summary()

number_of_epochs = 50
vgg16_history = vgg16_final_model.fit(train_generator, 
                                      epochs = number_of_epochs,
                                      validation_data = val_generator,
                                      callbacks=[early_stopping, reduceLR],
                                      verbose=1)
```

Here is the learning curves:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the classification confusion matrix; this *might* give some insight as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you've set all the layers as non-trainable:

```
for layers in vgg16_model.layers:
        layers.trainable=False
```

In this case, the network will use the weights from ImageNet, since you've imported the model setting *weights = 'imagenet'*. Looks like the dense layers are not sufficient for convergence. To fix this, it might be useful to set *layers_trainable=True* in the above loop.

Another way is simply pre-training your model, that is, importing no weights and training it on your own dataset.

Increasing the number of FC layers might be useful, but I think that is an improvement and not the core of the current problem.

Taking advantage of this, I'll give you some tips:

1. *class_mode* parameter in *flow_from_directory* function. Set from "sparse" to "categorical". As you can see in the docs *"sparse" will be 1D integer labels*, that is 1,2,3,...,7. This kind of label may be hard to learn. Remember to change your loss function to "categorical_crossentropy" and test the results.
2. You need first to test your data on its own. Are the augmentations beneficial for the learning process? You must keep attention to what kind of augmentations you are doing. Do any of them harm your data structure?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I set the layers_trainable as True then I have to train my model on millions of VGG16 weights which would take ages on my local machine and I also lose the pretrained weights. My plan was to fine-tune my model by unfreezing maybe two last layer of VGG16 to learn from my data as well. I examine your advice on the class_mode and how the model would do  with no augmentation

Comment: yeah, if your local machine has low process capability then a fine-tuning might be good. Let me know if the tips help you.